# Show that $\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x-c} =0$ has only two real roots

Tags: calculus

> I need help proving that the next equation has only two roots (under $\mathbb R$)
>   $$\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x-c} =0$$
>   $$a\lt b\lt c$$

Here is what I tried:

If I define a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x-c}$ I could show that this is a continuous function and for different values I get positive  or negative values and by the continuity it will be equal 0 exactly twice.

Maybe it has something to do with the function derivative?

Any ideas?

Comment: If $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ then $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = $ that thing.  $f$ vanishes at $a,b,c$ use Rolle to get that $f'$ does vanish at least twice. Use its degree to show that no more than twice.

Comment: "I could show that this is a continuous function" No. This is *not* a continuous function on ${\bf R}$.

Comment: Multiply by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ and solve the quadratic. Note that the reduced discriminant is$a^2 +b^2 + c^2 - a b - b c - a c \gt 0\,$.

Comment: @Jack yeah true, that was very stupid of me,

Comment: no this discriminat is $$\geq 0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Assuming you refer to my previous comment, the discriminant is $0$ iff $a=b=c$. In this case it is given that $a \lt b \lt c$ so the discriminant is strictly $\,\gt 0\,$, as written.

Comment: yes ok you have right, but the condition $$a<b<c$$ is not naturally

Comment: You can have a look also at this slightly different version, with any number of roots, but the principle is the same : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275845/proving-it-has-all-real-roots/2275912#2275912

Answer (score 0):

factorizing the whole Thing we obtaine:
$$-ab-ac+2\,ax-bc+2\,bx+2\,xc-3\,{x}^{2}=0$$
can you solve this?
solving this equation we get
$$x_1=a/3+b/3+c/3+1/3\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}-ab-ac+{b}^{2}-bc+{c}^{2}}$$
or
$$x_2=a/3+b/3+c/3-1/3\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}-ab-ac+{b}^{2}-bc+{c}^{2}}$$
note that we have $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$

Comment: this is a second order equation. if the determinant larger than 0 then is it has two solutions. but I don't see how to show it.

Comment: this inequality holds for all real $$a,b,c$$

Comment: it is easy to ptove this, but not with $-1$

Comment: No one should ever try to solve this question this way. Horrible.

Comment: ok we have $$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca=(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: @segevp $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca = \dfrac{(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2}{2} \ge 0$

Comment: this was an old matheolympiad Problem, which we have solved with our students

Comment: "which we have solved with our students" And you solved it this way? Poor students...

Comment: yes we solved it in this way since we have discussed the inequality $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$ which holds for all real numbers