# Prove the following for the given expression

Tags: functions, polynomials, exponential-function, quadratics

Consider the equation $$\frac{\pi ^e}{(x-e)} + \frac{e^{\pi}}{(x-\pi)} + \frac{\pi^{\pi}+e^e}{(x-e-\pi)}=0$$
Prove that

1) This equation has two real roots in $(\pi-e, \pi +e) $

2) This equation has one real root in $(e,\pi)$ and other root in $(\pi, e+\pi)$

My approach : Let $$f(x)=\frac{\pi ^e}{(x-e)} + \frac{e^{\pi}}{(x-\pi)} + \frac{\pi^{\pi}+e^e}{(x-e-\pi)}$$. Then I tried to find the sign of $f(\pi-e)f(\pi +e)$ so as to check for its sign to prove the first part. But this gives me a very tedious equation from which determining the sign is difficult. Moreover $f(\pi +e)$ creates a 0 in the denominator in third term.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1: Can anyone prove this using the properties and fundamentals just of polynomials. I know that maths is meant to learn what you don't understand but at current I want to know if this question can be solved using only the fundamentals of algebra and the polynomials without use of calculus

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=\pi$ and $x=e$. So knowing the values as $\pi-e$ and $\pi+e$ is only going to go so far.

Comment: And it's undefined at $x=\pi+e$ too.

Comment: Notice that $f'(x)<0$ so $f$ continuous and is $\searrow$ in $4$ intervals, and since limits in the poles are $\pm\infty$ you can apply IVT. Have a look at this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275845/proving-it-has-all-real-roots

Comment: The 'graph-theory' tag is not correct here. See : https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph-theory/info

Comment: "not like the existing answers which use limits and some part of calculus" The method I've employed in my answer almost _touches_ and _instantaneously leaves_ the domain of calculus and limits ;) I highly doubt it can get any simpler than that. But it'll be good to know of newer methods nonetheless :)

Comment: @GaurangTandon I know your method is quite different( and hence I had upvoted it long time back)  but the methods prescribed are much similar with a blend of variety and I needed something that is very unique and probably the most "unnatural" way to think for this question

Comment: @Manthanein Definitely I'm in complete agreement :)

Answer (score 1):

multiply out the term
$$\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)+e^\pi(x-e)(x-e-\pi)+(\pi^\pi+e^e)(x-e)(x-\pi)=...$$
ok then consider
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi^e}{x-e}+\frac{e^\pi}{x-\pi}+\frac{\pi^\pi+e^e}{x-e-\pi}$$
and compute $$f(\pi-e)\approx -27.7935443004972883808036072099123560713149915<0$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \pi+e}f(x)=+\infty$$

Comment: ok we get an quadratic equation in $x$

Comment: But that won't suffice to prove that there would be two real roots in  $(\pi-e, \pi +e) $.

Comment: on Moment i will post it

Comment: i will send you my answer

Comment: I enjoy the $\approx$ !

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying out the denominator into the numerator we get:

$$f(x)=\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)+e^\pi(x-e)(x-e-\pi)+(\pi^\pi+e^e)(x-e)(x-\pi)$$

**I'll show you how to prove the part about $(e,\pi)$**, the other proofs are similar. This proof does not use any complex quadratic formula or tough arithmetic calculation.

Take $x_1=e+h$, where $h$ is a very small number $\approx10^{-20}>0$. Compute

$$f(x_1)=\color{green}{\pi^e(e-\pi+h)(-\pi+h)}+\color{blue}{e^\pi(h)(-\pi+h)}+\color{blue}{(\pi^\pi+e^e)(h)(e-\pi+h)}$$

Since $h$ is very very small, we can almost equate $\color{blue}{h\cdot\text{constant value}\approx0}$ and $\color{green}{\text{constant}+h\approx\text{constant}}$. Hence, we get:
$$f(x_1)\approx\pi^e(e-\pi)(-\pi)>0$$

Now, take $x_2=\pi-h$. Computing $f(x_2)$ by similar logic, we get:
$$f(x_2)=e^\pi(\pi-e)(-e)<0$$

Since $f(x)$ has changed sign in the interval $(e,\pi)$, this implies that it must have crossed the x-axis at some $x_0\in(e,\pi)$ as it is a continuous function. Hence, $f(x_0)=0$ and thus $f(x)$ has a root in $(e,\pi)$.

---

For the first proof, you'll need to break the given interval of $(\pi-e,\pi+e)$ at some suitable value of $x'$. Then use the same logic as described above, to prove the existence of one real root each in $(\pi-e,x')$ and $(x',\pi+e)$, for a total of two real roots.

---

Can you solve this on your own from here now?

---

**PS**: (since you mentioned you don't have much experience of limits) The technique of taking $h$ is essentially me showing you how to take the Left hand Limits and Right Hand Limits of $f(x)$ without actually mentioning the scary terminology! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\notin\{e,\pi,e+\pi\}$ then multiplying both sides by $(x-e)(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)$ gives
$$(x-e)(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)f(x)=g(x)$$
where 
$$g(x):=\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)+e^\pi(x-e)(x-e-\pi)+(\pi^\pi+e^e)(x-e)(x-\pi)$$
Clearly $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree two hence a quadratic polynomial. Moreover the coefficients are all real so if one root of $g(x)$ is real the other one must be real as well. Now you can do a sign check of $g(x)$. Since we excluded $e,\pi,e+\pi$ we are only allowed to approach these values in our argument. So if $x$ is close to $e$ from the right side the second and third term are negligible since $x-e$ becomes smaller and smaller almost zero. So the first term dominates. Since $e<\pi$ then $g(x)>0$ for $x$ close to $e$. Similarly we approach $\pi$ from the left. Again the first and the third term become negligibly small so the middle term dominates. Since $\pi>e$ then $g(x)<0$ for $x$ close to $\pi$. But $g(x)$ is a polynomial so a continuous function therefore there exists some $x_1\in(e,\pi)$ where $g(x_1)=0$ (by Intermediate Value Theorem). The same analysis for the interval $(\pi,e+\pi)$. These are the only two roots of $g(x)$. But from the main equation that relates $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ it then follows that indeed these are the roots also for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\pi ^e}{(x-e)} + \frac{e^{\pi}}{(x-\pi)} + \frac{\pi^{\pi}+e^e}{(x-e-\pi)}.$

Thus, $f$ is a continuous function on $(\pi,\pi+e)$ and on $(e,\pi)$ and calculate four limits of $f$ in these bounds.

For example, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi+e^-}f(x)=-\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pi^+}f(x)=+\infty$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't have much idea of limits or of higher calculus. This question was actually asked to me in a test of chapter of polynomials

Answer (score 0):

First, we multiply the expression by each of the denominators to rewrite the expression as $\pi^e(x-\pi)(x-e-\pi)+e^\pi(x-e)(x-e-\pi) + (\pi^{\pi}+e^e)(x-e)(x-\pi)=0$ where $x$ is not $e, \pi$, or $e + \pi$ (since the original expression is not defined for those values). Call that polynomial $g(x)$. When this polynomial has a root that is not $e, \pi$, or $e + \pi$, then such a root is a solution to the original equation. So lets use this to answer the questions (note that $\pi > e > \pi - e$):

1) If we have part 2 then part 1 follows since if we have a solution in $(e,\pi)$ and another solution in $(\pi,e+\pi)$, then the two solutions are both contained in $(e,e+\pi)$ which is a subset of $(\pi-e,\pi+e)$ since $e>\pi-e$.

2) Notice that:

- $g(e) = \pi^e(e-\pi)(-\pi)>0$
- $g(\pi) = e^\pi(\pi - e)(-e)<0$
- $g(e + \pi) = (\pi^{\pi}+e^e)(\pi)(e)>0$

So $g(x)$ must be $0$ for some $x$ in $(e,\pi)$ and for another $x$ in $(\pi,e+\pi)$. Note that neither of these solutions are any of $e, \pi$, or $e + \pi$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

---

THE PROOF

Substitution 
$$y=x-\pi - e,\quad x = y +\pi +e,$$
leads to the equation
$$f(y) = \pi^ey(y+e)+e^\pi y(y+\pi)+(\pi^\pi+e^e)(y+e)(y+\pi) = 0.\tag1$$
Easy to see that for continuous function $f(y)$
$$f(-\pi) = \pi^e\pi(\pi-e)>0,\quad f(-e) = -e^\pi e(\pi-e)<0,\quad f(0) = e\pi(\pi^\pi+e^e)>0,$$
so for the roots of the issue function $x_{_1} < x_{_2}$
$$\boxed {x_{_1}\in(e,\pi),\quad x_{_2}\in (\pi, \pi+e)}.$$

---

MORE ABOUT SOLUTIONS

Equation $(1)$ can be presented in the form of
$$\left(2p+2q-1\right)y^2+2(p\pi+qe)y+e\pi = 0,\tag2$$
where
$$p=\dfrac12\dfrac{\pi^e+\pi^\pi+e^e}{\pi^\pi+e^e}\approx 0.717558258728198503529338558986694826489131048822891627548,$$
$$q = \dfrac12\dfrac{e^\pi+\pi^\pi+e^e}{\pi^\pi+e^e}\quad \approx 0.724160178136871712919110626691079457286566485261309347358.$$
The discriminant of (2) is
$$D=(p\pi+qe)^2-(2p+2q-1)\pi e=(p\pi-qe)^2 + (3-2p-2q)\pi e >0,$$
and the exact solutions of the issue equation are
$$\boxed{x_{_{1,2}}=\pi+e+\dfrac{-(p\pi+qe)\pm\sqrt D}{2p+2q-1}},$$
$$x_1\approx 2.909741688012856092190981170549535094702484004984660834471.$$
$$x_2\approx 4.322952859602067483788142878540635723540552275102155350235,$$
Substitution of the values
$$p \approx q \approx 0.72$$
to $(2)$ allows to get the equation
$$47y^2 +36(\pi+e)y+25e\pi = 0,$$
which leads to the approximate solutions of the issue equation
$$\boxed{x_{_{1,2}} \approx \dfrac1{47}\left(29e + 29\pi\pm\sqrt{324(\pi-e)^2 + 121e\pi}\ \right)},$$
$$x_{_1}\approx 2.913,\quad x_{_2}\approx 4.319.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\neq b,d,f$, we have the equation $$\begin{align}\frac a{x-b}+\frac c{x-d}+\frac g{x-f}=0&\implies \small a(x-d)(x-f)+c(x-b)(x-f)+g(x-b)(x-d)=0\\&\implies\small(a+c+g)x^2-[a(d+f)+c(b+f)+g(b+d)]x+adf+bcf+bdg=0\end{align}$$ Hence

> $$\begin{align}\small x&=\small\frac{[a(d+f)+c(b+f)+g(b+d)]\pm\sqrt{[a(d+f)+c(b+f)+g(b+d)]^2-4(a+c+g)(adf+bcf+bdg)}}{2(a+c+g)}\end{align}$$

Substituting $a=\pi^e$, $b=e$, $c=e^\pi$, $d=\pi$, $g=\pi^\pi+e^e$ and $f=e+\pi$, we get $$x=\frac{703.135601...\pm\sqrt{494399.674629...-475524.453356...}}{194.432544...}=2.909741...,4.322952...$$

> Now $(\pi-e,e+\pi)=(0.42...,5.85...)$ and we see that both solutions lie in this interval.
>
> Also, $2.909741...\in(e,\pi)$ and $4.322952\in(\pi,e+\pi)$ and so the proof is complete.