# Solutions of $\ f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a_1} + \frac{1}{x-a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x-a_n} $

Tags: functions, derivatives, summation

I got $\ a_1, \ldots,a_n $ as different real numbers  and:

$$\ f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a_1} + \frac{1}{x-a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x-a_n} $$

I have to find the number of the solutions in real numbers for$\ f(x) = 0$ and $\ f(x) = x$.

I notice, that:

$$\ \frac{x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}(a_1+\cdots+a_n)-x^{n-3}(\cdots }{x^n-x^{n-1}(a_1+\cdots+a_n)\cdots} $$

In nominator therre always lacks a one real number because of the multiplication to the common denominator - in denominator there are all $\ a's$.

Here I ask you for help. I'm stuck on this, although I think of derivative and comparison to i.e.
$$\  x = \frac{1}{x-a_1} + \frac{1}{x-a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x-a_n} $$

I would appreciate any explanation or advice.

Comment: Your question in the first case is equivalent to finding the number of real roots of $p’(x)=0$ . In the case of $p’(x)=0$ you can use Rolle’s theorem to conclude that there are $n—1$ real roots.

Comment: In the second case you need the number of real roots of $p’(x)-xp(x)=0$

Comment: We have n-1 intervals $\ (a_i, a_{i+1},=) $, where the function is contiunuous and has a derivative. However, I would like to ask you kindly for explanation: what does derivative has in common with normal function in this case? Additionally, could you explain your solution to the second case?

Comment: It is very similar to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275845/proving-it-has-all-real-roots/2275912#2275912, note that when derivating $f$ is decreasing on every interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$

Answer (score 1):

It is known that in the complex case $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z-a_i}$ by the logarithmic derivative of $p$ and each term $z-a_i$. 
In your case you have $\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}=0$ and thus as you noted in each interval $(a_i,a_{i+1})$, $p'(x)=0$ has exactly one real root.

For the second case I would suggest a different approach though than the one in my comment. Let $z_0\in\mathbb{C}: \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z_0-a_i}=z_0$ then $z_0=\Re(z_0)+i\Im(z_0)$ and thus if $\Im(z_0)\ne{}0$ then all $\Im(\frac{1}{z_0-a_i})$ have the same sign which is different from the sign of $\Im(z_0)$ thus forcing $\Im(z_0)=0$ and $z_0\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_1 < ... < a_n$. The idea here is that $f(x)$ decreases from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ as $x$ increases from each $a_i$ to each $a_{i+1}$, $f(x)$ decreases from $0$ to $-\infty$ as $x$ increases from $-\infty$ to $a_1$, and $f(x)$ decreases from $\infty$ to $0$ as $x$ increases from $a_n$ to $\infty$.

Based on the above, $f(x)$ has $n-1$ zeroes, one between each $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$. As for solutions to $f(x) = x$, the increasing graph of $y = x$ will intersect each of the decreasing pieces of the graph of $f(x)$ exactly once, so there will be $n+1$ intersections overall.

Comment: Indeed, very clear and useful, however, I would like you to write more on the pharse "The intersecting graph y=x...". I am wondering wher is n'th and (n+1)'th intersection, I can't visualize it.

Comment: As $x$ approaches $x_n$ from the right, $f(x)$ approaches $\infty$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$. So on the interval $(a_n,\infty)$, $f(x)$ decreases from $\infty$ to $0$. On the other hand, on the same interval $(a_n,\infty)$, $y = x$ increases from $a_n$ to $\infty$. Hence for $x$ large enough, $x > f(x)$, and for $x$ close enough to $a_n$ on the right $x < f(x)$. Because $x - f(x)$ is increasing, there is therefore exactly one $x \in (a_n,\infty)$ where $x - f(x) = 0$ i.e. $x = f(x)$. A similar analysis works for the other intersection points.